# Using local Perl module instead of one installed by CPAN

Tags: perl, cpan

I have found it necessary to expand upon a CPAN module. (Unicode::CharName goes up to Unicode 4.1; I need some characters from Unicode 5.0 & 5.1).

I've made the changes needed and have my own CharName.pm module.

I now would like to use it with my various Perls. I currently use:

- Strawberry Perl for Windows
- git for Windows MINGW64; My .bashrc sets
  $PATH to Strawberry perl and   $PERL5LIB=/c/Strawberry/perl/vendor/lib:/c/Strawberry/perl/site/lib
- WSL Ubuntu

Where should I put my version of Unicode::CharName, so that it over-rides the ones installed by CPAN?

I don't want to have to change any scripts that currently

```
use Unicode::CharName;
```

Comment: You could use the Core module `charnames`'s `viacode`. Support for Unicode 5.0 was added in Perl 5.10 and 5.2 in 5.12. (Perl 5.30 supports Unicode 12.1.)

Comment: *"Where should I put my version of Unicode::CharName"* Write a simple `Makefile.PL` for you module, see [ExtUtils::MakeMaker](https://perldoc.perl.org/ExtUtils/MakeMaker.html) and then run `perl Makefile.PL; make; make install` it should overwrite the original module.

Comment: @ikegami, 1) I don't want to change the calling script. As well Unicode::CharName gives me the Unicode block name as well.

Comment: Note to potential answerers: This question has been crossposted to PerlMonks at https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=11103047

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [cpanm](https://metacpan.org/pod/cpanm) you could download the module, patch it, and install it as normal:

```
$ cpanm --look Unicode::CharName
# new shell opens
$ patch lib/Unicode/CharName.pm custom.patch # or whatever process
$ perl Makefile.PL
$ make install
$ exit
```

You can also install it to a [local::lib](https://metacpan.org/pod/local::lib) to avoid overwriting it globally, by adding the `-l local/` option to the `cpanm` command. Then you can add the absolute path of this local::lib to your PERL5LIB or via `-I` or `use lib`. If you specified `/path/to/local` for the `-l` option, it would be `/path/to/local/lib/perl5`.

Manually copying files rather than going through the normal installation process is likely to lead to problems. Many distributions depend on the installation process to build the modules correctly. Also, you will need to install the module separately for each Perl you want to use it for; installed Perl modules are not generally cross-compatible between Perl versions or architectures. (A strictly simple pure-Perl module can be an exception to these rules, but the only module I feel comfortable abusing this way is App::cpanminus, because it was designed to do this.)